Parent object and vertex
I have a problem with parent. How do I insert parent object and parent vertex without conflicting them?

Hello could you please tell a bit more, why are you trying to do it and so on?

Hello, ale_bbb, welcome..  this is too abstract.. it's not clear .. are you trying to make one child-object  both vertex-parented and object-parented to another object? (That's not possible) Instead, present us with the problem you are looking to solve, this way, and I'm sure there will be a way.

I should do the animation of a robotic arm with inflatable links (links are robot arms). I made the links through a YouTube video. To be able to move these from a wrinkle position to a wrinkle-free position I have to go through edit mode. I realized that the only parent that worked so that the links swelled up and all the parts of the arm moved together were vertex. but I also need the parent object to change the position of the arm motor and make the rotate

An object cannot have more than one parent. You can use a parent constraint (which is essentially fake parenting) with the influence animated to dynamically switch what an object is effectively parented to, and the constraint will override the real parenting, but you can only have one real parent per object.
See The Blender Manual page on Parenting Objects for more information.
If this is not the answer you were looking for, please add details to your question. Hope this helps!
